# ReactJS link to local HTML file from different folder/project

Tags: html, reactjs, webpack-html-loader

I'm using ReactJS to build a site, and I want to create a link (a href="relativepath") to a local HTML file so that when the user clicks on the link, it'll open up the html page. The local file is in a different folder X outside of the project, and I don't want to upload it into my src folder because the html file depends on a lot of other files in X. Is there a good way to do so?

I also want to upload a different local HTML file that is already within the src folder of my React App. I currently have something like this:
`import htmlFile from "../links/htmlFile.html"; export default function Something(props) { return (<a href={htmlFile}></a>)}`
and it says in my terminal that

> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> `> <html>| | <head>` >

I already tried adding in webpack + an htmlLoader, but I think I followed the steps incorrectly as I wasn't able to get it to work. I uninstalled those packages, so I'm now back to square one.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just linking to or importing from a local file in some other location won't work unless those local files are also deployed to the server in the same location relative to the app (and the web server has access to that location).

So you'll need to copy the file and its linked dependencies in a folder that will be deployed along with your react build, but not where it'll get treated as part of the react codebase so webpack will try to compile it (so not in `src` either).

If you used `create-react-app` to set up your application, for example, this would be [the `public` folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/); other webpack setups may use different names but the general concept is the same.